# Every ball in different urn

Tags: probability, statistics, balls-in-bins

We've got $n$ urns, I have to show that for some $c>0$ there are $c \sqrt{n}$ balls, that after putting them inside urns, probability that all the urns have at most 1 ball is equal or lower than $\frac{1}{e}$.

I know that there are $\frac{n!}{(n-c\sqrt{n})!}$ different cases of putting $c\sqrt{n}$ balls following mentioned assumption (first ball can be thrown to $n$ different urns, second to $n-1$, $c \sqrt{n}$ ball to $n-c\sqrt{n}+1$ urns) and there are $n^{c\sqrt{n}}$ all cases of putting these balls inside $n$ urns.

Probability is the division of these two components, but how it can be compared to $e^{-1}$? I've got a hint to use inequality $e^{-x} \ge 1-x$, but after determining probabilities of these two events and dividing first by second, I don't know what to do next.

Edit
So, using Stirling formula I've got $\frac{\frac{n!}{(n-c\sqrt{n})!}}{n^{c\sqrt{n}}}$ which is about $\sqrt{2\pi n} (\frac{n}{e})^n \cdot (\sqrt{2\pi (n-c\sqrt{n})} (\frac{n-c\sqrt{n}}{e})^{c\sqrt{n}})^{-1} \cdot (n^{c\sqrt{n}})^{-1}$

I simplified it into $\sqrt{\frac{n}{n-c\sqrt{n}}} \cdot (\frac{n}{n-c\sqrt{n}})^{n-c\sqrt{n}} \cdot e^{-c\sqrt{n}}$

But now I'm stuck again and I'm not certain if that Stirling approximation is greater or lower than previous fraction.

Comment: Seems like using Stirling’s formula would prove useful.

Comment: @NL1992 I used it, you can see my results, but I'm stuck again.

Comment: Hi, sorry, I seem to have misread what you wrote. Gave a detailed answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of possibilities of putting $c\sqrt n$ balls into $n$ urns s.t. each has his own urn is actually $n\choose c\sqrt n$.

The number of different ways of putting $c\sqrt n$ balls into $n$ urns is given by the probability of dividing $c\sqrt n$ objects to $n$ cells, which is known to be given by $n+c\sqrt n-1\choose n-1$.

From these two quantities we obtain:
$$
{n\choose c\sqrt n} / {n+c\sqrt n-1\choose n-1}=\prod_{i=1}^{c\sqrt n - 1}\frac{n-c\sqrt n+i} {n+i}=\prod_{i=1}^{c\sqrt n - 1}1 -\frac{c\sqrt n} {n+i}
\leq\prod_{i=1}^{c\sqrt n - 1}1 -\frac{c\sqrt n} {2n}\leq(1-c/2\sqrt n)^{c\sqrt n}\\
\leq e^{\frac{-c} {2\sqrt n}\cdot c\sqrt n}=e^{-c^2/2}
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I've got 2 questions - first is about all different ways of putting $c\sqrt{n}$ balls into $n$ urns, I don't get it, and I can't find some any example where this formula is mentioned. Second is the division, after dividing these two Netwon symbols I've got other result than you - it's $n!(n-1)!(c\sqrt{n})! / (c\sqrt{n})!(n-c\sqrt{n})!(n+c\sqrt{n}-1)!$ which can't be shorten to the product you showed

Comment: @jakub1998 it is exactly what I got for the product. Cancel the $c\sqrt n$ and you can see that the enumerator is the product of numbers from $n-c\sqrt n$ to $n-1$ while the denominator is $n+1$ to $n+c\sqrt n-1$.

Comment: For the first part, see theorem 2: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)